# Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrayss

Tags: angular, mongodb, web

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { AnyArray } from 'mongoose';
import { DataService } from '../../services/data.service';





@Component({
  selector: 'app-allpatients',
  templateUrl: './allpatients.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./allpatients.component.css']
})
export class AllpatientsComponent implements OnInit {
  
  dataArray:any
  constructor(private ds:DataService){
    this.ds.getAllPatients().subscribe(data=>this.dataArray=data);
   
  }

  
 
ngOnInit(): void{

}
}
```

/////////////////////// and this is my data.service.ts//////////////////////////////////

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {  }

  getAllPatients(){
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/patients')
  }



 
}
```

So what should I change so it can work?

please I'm stuck and I don't know what I should change on my code

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that `DataService` is returning an `Object` not an `Array`.

You can either use the `keyvalue` pipe and display it as an object:

```
  <div
    *ngFor="let item of dataArray | keyvalue" >
    <p>{{ item.key }} : {{ item.value }}</p>
  </div>
```

Or make sure dataArray is actually an Array and display it.

```
  <div
    *ngFor="let item of dataArray" >
    <p>{{ item }}</p>
  </div>
```

Also, you can click `edit` button below your question to edit it after posting